# How to extract GPS information from video stream

Tags: video, gps, garmin

I just got a Garmin Virb Elite video recorder and recorded some videos with it, and also confirmed that Garmins own player can show the GPS information on a Map.

This video recorder stores GPS data on a separate .gpx file which can be easily opened text (xml) editors.

I'm rather sure that gps data also recorded into the video stream as riff  with sequential same bytes of data (chunk).

I'm looking for some information which help me to extract these data using C#.